# Python mocking with parameter evaluation

Tags: python, mocking

i have a problem when using the patch decorator for mocking a method in python.

the goal is to overwrite the following function call

```
self.util.database.getLatestPrice(token)

def getLatestPrice(self, token) -> Price | None:
```

and transport the input parameters.

```
    def mockedLatestPrice(self, token):
        return self.testUtil.util.database.getHistoryPrice(token, self.time)

    @mock.patch.object(Db, "getLatestPrice", side_effect=mockedLatestPrice)
    def testStrategyWithHistory(self, mock):
        strategy = Strategy(self.testUtil)
        for i in range(1, self.days, 1):
            for j in range(1, 1440, 1):
                logging.info(f"run day {i}, minute {j}:")
                strategy.runStrategy()
                self.nextTime()
```

i also tried it with side_effect=mockedLatestPrice(token) but it is not working.
do i need to use kwargs?

the error message i got is:

```
TypeError: Test.mockedLatestPrice() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

hope s.o. can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `mockedLatestPrice` is an instance method of the TestCase, but  when you pass it as `side_effect=mockedLatestPrice` that method is not yet bound (because TestCase class is not fully defined yet).

So the token is getting passed to `self` and the `token` arg is missing.

Try this:

```py
    def testStrategyWithHistory(self):
        with mock.patch.object(
            Db, "getLatestPrice", side_effect=self.mockedLatestPrice
        ) as mock:
            strategy = Strategy(self.testUtil)
            for i in range(1, self.days, 1):
                for j in range(1, 1440, 1):
                    logging.info(f"run day {i}, minute {j}:")
                    strategy.runStrategy()
                    self.nextTime()
```